# Equation error double superscript

Tags: equations

```
## [16]
! Double superscript.
l.44 x[n]=A*e^{-^
                \delta ^n}*cos(2\pi f_0n-\phi)
?  ##
```

My code:

---

```
\begin{equation}\label{Exponential }
x[n]=A*e^{-^\delta ^n}*cos(2\pi f_0 n-\phi)
\end{equation}
```

---

```
 -
```

## new Error

```
: ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again> 
                       \protect l.17 ...trization in Time Domain}{equation.3.1}{}}

    ?
```

### my file:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}  Standard-Layout f�r das Dokument
    \usepackage{lmodern} 
    \parindent0pt 
    \usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.20}\normalsize 



    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
    \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} 
    \usepackage{textcomp} 


    \usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{mathrsfs,amssymb} 
    \usepackage{icomma} 
    \usepackage{mathtools} 
    \usepackage{theorem} 
    \numberwithin{equation}{section} 
    \usepackage{commath} 
    \usepackage{bm} 


    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
    \definecolor{dunkelblau}{rgb}{0,0,0.5} 
    \definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
    \definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
    \definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
    \definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
    \definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}

    \numberwithin{figure}{section} 

    \usepackage{subfig} 
    \usepackage{graphicx} 


    \usepackage[automark]{scrpage2} 
    \pagestyle{scrheadings} 
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \ihead[]{\headmark} 
    \ohead[]{\pagemark} 
    \cfoot[\pagemark]{}
    \setheadsepline{0.4pt} 
    \setlength{\headheight}{1 cm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{1 cm}

    %++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    %Zus�tzliche Pakete
    %++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    \usepackage[colorlinks=false,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref} 

    \usepackage{pdfpages} 
    \usepackage{listings} 
    \usepackage[square,numbers,comma, sort & compress]{natbib}
    \usepackage{leftidx} 
    \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode} 

    \numberwithin{table}{section} 



    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
    \DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
    \DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
    \DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}
    \usepackage{epigraph}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \label{Exponential decaying }
    x[n]=A*e^{-\delta n}*cos(2\pi f_0 n-\phi)
    %x\left [ n \right ]=A*e^{-\delta n}*cos(2\pi f_0 n-\phi)
    \end{equation}

    Where,\\
    \begin{align}
    A: Amplitude\\
    %
    \delta: Exponential decaying constant\\
    %
    f_0:frequency [Hz]\\
    %
    \omega_0: 2\pi f_0 [rad/sec]\\
    %
    \phi: Phase [rad]\\
    %
    n: Number of samples\\
    \end{align}
    Similarly, in Continuous time
    \begin{equation}\label{Exponen}
    x(c)=A*e^{-\delta c}*cos(2\pi f_0 t-\phi)
    \end{equation}

    Where,\\

    \begin{align}
    A: Amplitudii\\
    %
    \omez_0: 2\\\
    %
    \phi: Phas\\
    %
    c: Contin\\
    %
    T: Sampli
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have a `-` superscripted by both delta and n: `-^\delta ^n`

Comment: please always provide a small complete document that people can run, you have two superscripts here but don't you want none? shouldn't that be `{-\delta n}` ?

Comment: it's not really the way the site works to _completely alter_ the question after answers have been posted. It makes if very hard for people reading later to understand what is going on.

Comment: why do you have `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}` ? No documents written after 1993 should have `\rm`, some classes define `\rm` using that form for documents from the 1980s that were old in 1993, why add it to a new document this century?

Comment: never put `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph like `Where,\\ ` (you must get warnings about that.

Comment: If you want to ask about the new error open a new question, but in it include a complete document (your fragment has no `\end{document}` so will make no output, and clearly does not make the error shown as the letters `trization in Time Domain` do not appear in the code.

Comment: sorry. I am actually new on this website so i have problem to upload the question in good manner. I will take care about it next time. Thank you but for your preccious time which you are giving.

Comment: \DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm} this my university document format. I am not allowed to edit that.

Comment: it's still wrong, even if it's not your fault:-)

Comment: should i need to remove it to solve the problem? could you suggest me what i need to write to replace \DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm} with

Comment: it's unrelated to the problem, it was just a comment. Your document should not be using `\rm` so there is no need to  define it. the code you post has several errors eg missing comment on line 1, and undefined command `\omez` but no error related to the one that you posted.  but as I say best to remove that from here and ask a new question, but make sure the code that you post generates the error that you post, don't post an error message from a  different document

Comment: i will post it Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you show is not generated by the code that you posted, and seems very strange as it is reporting an error at the *first* superscript.

The error is on the second superscript and should look like

```
! Double superscript.
l.6 x[n]=A*e^{-^\delta ^
                        n}*cos(2\pi f_0 n-\phi)
?
```

the - sign has two superscripts but I think you don't want to superscript it at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{Exponential }
x[n]=A*e^{-\delta n}*\cos(2\pi f_0 n-\phi)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

note `\cos` not `cos` (I wouldn't normally use `*` for multiplication either)

Comment: Thank you very much but i am getting now another error. Just a moment i am uploading my full file. Thank you for your help